# Enable a disabled account on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, user-accounts, undelete, deleted-accounts

I had two accounts on Stack Overflow, one is for official use and other is for personal use, as our office has a weird policy about not to use personal accounts anywhere.

I had plans to quit my job, so I added my personal account's login information to my official account's login information and then deleted my official login.

But now I lost my personal accounts, Currently that account is referring as user831174. Is there any way I could revive that account? I understand that I can't use a single email for two accounts, but how to revive it even for other email account?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous)

Answer (score 6):

If you wish to have your older personal account restored, write to the Stack Exchange team via the [contact us](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/contact) link and indicate the that you'd like a particular account to be undeleted. I believe it is this one, in your case:

https://stackoverflow.com/users/831174/msingh

However, I should indicate that this account of yours was not removed merely for being another account by the same person. It's perfectly fine to have multiple accounts, as long as they do not interact. Please do not use one of your accounts to vote for the other, because we do remove accounts that are used to do this.

Comment: and  could I have two a personal and other for a work in stackoverflow?

Comment: @Simon - As long as they do not interact with each other (no cross-voting, asking questions for the other to answer, accepting each other's edits, etc.) and they aren't being used to evade suspensions, question limits, or other system-imposed restrictions.