# how join two account from stackoverflow

Tags: discussion, login, user-accounts

I am new.

> I have two account on stackoverflow a personal and other for my work
> like developer and I think that moderators  think  , that I have
> multiple account and they say me that "please stop create multiple
> account maybe I made some mistake I did not know is permit create more
> a account.

**my question are:**

should I have two account a personal and other for my work or should I join to two
account?

how I could contact with a moderador from stackoverflow for explain you that is not my  intentation create two account if  I could join to two account.

Comment: see also: [How can one link / merge / combine / associate two accounts / users? (Anonymous / unregistered / cookie, or OpenID / registered)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18232/165773)

Answer (score 5):

As I mentioned in my comment [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/193564/enable-a-disabled-account-on-stack-overflow/193590#comment1025910_193590), it's fine to have multiple accounts as long as you aren't using them to do something that you couldn't do with a single account.

This includes using multiple accounts to bypass system restrictions on asking. We deleted your two additional accounts on Stack Overflow because your year-old main account was banned from asking questions and it appeared you were using those new accounts to evade that question ban.

Please do not create new accounts to work around system-imposed restrictions. Instead, work on improving the questions on your main account and try to contribute in a positive manner with that account first.

Comment: how I could join to my two account in a ?

Comment: @Simon - As gnat links above, you need to follow the instructions here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts